# How I can make event listener(change) fot items with vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, dom-events

How do I run the same action for each event. When the user selects an option, I need to show a table. And when they select another, show another table. But the tables were getting shown one by one. So I added an action for removing, but now the table only appears half the time. How can I make a select event lister, that does not disappear after the second click and not repeat tables

```
function getTableRegion(select, divResutl) {
    select.addEventListener('change', function (ev) {
        cleanMessage(divResutl);
        console.log(ev)
        if (document.getElementById('table')) {
            divResutl.removeChild(document.getElementById('table'))
        } else {
            let tbody = document.createElement('tbody');
            let table = document.createElement('table');
            table.id = 'table';
            table.setAttribute('style', 'display:table');
            tbody.innerHTML = `<tr><th>Country name</th>
                                 <th>Capital</th><th>World region</th><th>Languages</th>
                                  <th>Area</th><th>Flag </th></th></tr>`;
            table.append(tbody);
            divResutl.append(table);
        }
    })
}
```

Thank you

Comment: If you have two tables, each with id 'table', the DOM gets confused as ids are unique.

Comment: You could just keep the same table and only change the `tbody.innerHTML` on change.

Comment: `table.setAttribute('style', 'display:table');` WHY?

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to do if/else. If it exists, remove it and add the next.

```
function getTableRegion(select, divResutl) {
  select.addEventListener('change', function(ev) {
    cleanMessage(divResutl);
    console.log(ev)
    if (document.getElementById('table')) {
      document.getElementById('table').remove();
    }
    let tbody = document.createElement('tbody');
    let table = document.createElement('table');
    table.id = 'table';
    tbody.innerHTML = `<tr><th>Country name</th>
                                     <th>Capital</th><th>World region</th><th>Languages</th>
                                      <th>Area</th><th>Flag </th></th></tr>`;
    table.append(tbody);
    divResutl.append(table);

  })
}
```